# Use Parse for professional project?

Tags: ios, web-services, parse-platform

I'm developing an app for iOS. I'd like to connect to a database to write users, passwords, some data related to them etc, so I discovered a thing called Parse. I've integrated it to my app and it works fine but I don't know if it's any limit (e.g. limit writes, limited in daily access... -I'm not paying any amount-).

Would you consider that it's better to program by myself a web service, an api, call it whatever, and make the write and read manually?

Comment: Please add a link to Parse project - it's not clean what the library you talking about. Tag would help but better to have a link in the post message

Comment: www.parse.com is the web

Comment: So just edit your post by adding the link to [parse.com](http://www.parse.com).

Answer (score 0):

The biggest limits with Parse are their API requests per limit. They start out at 30/s free and the it gets more expensive from there. So if you're never going to have that many users/API requests then it can remain free for some time.